# Calling base class method from derived class method

Tags: ruby

I have a method in my base class and I need to call this  method  from my derived class. Is it possible using static methods?

```
class base < A

  def self.method1
  end

end

class derived < base

  def method2
    base.method1
  end

end
```

Is it possible in this way? Is it correct?

Comment: In Ruby class name or module name always starts with capital letter, because class names and module names are constants.

Answer (score 8):

Yes..

```
class Base
  def self.method1
    p "hi"
  end
end
class Derived < Base
  def method2
    self.class.method1
  end
end
Derived.new.method2
# >> "hi"
```

Comment: Question (mildly unrelated): I don't think you can call a static method from a static method this way? In this example, if it was `self.method2`, then I think there would be this error: `undefined method 'method1' for Class:Class`.